# format localization placeholder with leading zero in Flutter

Tags: flutter, localization

Please help me to create the intl localization arb file

I'd like to have a localizable string with the placeholder for an integer value with leading zero if integer value is less than 10.

Here is a part of the `arb` file:

```yaml
  "notificationScheduled": "The notification has been scheduled for {min}:{sec}",
  "@notificationScheduled": {
    "placeholders": {
      "min": {
        "type": "int",
        "format": "decimalPattern",
        "example": "23"
      },
      "sec": {
        "type": "int",
        "format": "00",
        "example": "43"
      }
    }
  }
```

`min` value and `sec` values are supplied from the Dart code.

```dart
var min = 10;
var sec = 8;

Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.notificationScheduled(min, sec))
```

I'd like to have `sec` value for seconds formatted with leading zero if it is less than 10.
The problem is that both `0#` and `00` format strings are not accepted when `app_localizations` files are generated.

```
 flutter gen-l10n --template-arb-file=app_en.arb
```

raises error

```
Number format 00 for the sec placeholder does not have a corresponding NumberFormat constructor.
Check the intl library's NumberFormat class constructors for allowed number formats.
```

I've tried `optionalFormat` with `customPattern` and error has gone but there are no leading zero in the result string.

```
      "sec": {
        "type": "int",
        "format": "decimalPattern",
        "example": "43",
        "optionalParameters": {
            "decimalDigits": 0,
            "customPattern": "0#"
        }
      }
```

The `sec` value does not have leading zero when formatted with `customPattern:0#`.

The text value is like `10:8` but I'd like to have `10:08`.

Is it possible to adjust `arb` file localization format to have leading zero in the result string ?